# Why does Kubernetes apiserver present a bad certificate to the etcd server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, coreos

Running Kubernetes on CoreOS on an AWS EC2 instance, I am unable to execute [apiserver](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/kube-apiserver.html) via a hyperkube Docker container successfully. The problem is that the [etcd server](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/etcd.html) refuses connections due to a bad certificate.

What happens is this:

`$ docker run -v /etc/ssl/etcd:/etc/ssl/etcd:ro gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.2 /hyperkube apiserver --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1 --etcd-servers=https://172.31.29.111:2379 --allow-privileged=true --service-cluster-ip-range=10.3.0.0/24 --secure-port=443 --advertise-address=172.31.29.111 --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota --tls-cert-file=/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client.pem --tls-private-key-file=/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client-key.pem --client-ca-file=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem --kubelet-certificate-authority=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client.pem --kubelet-client-key=/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client-key.pem --kubelet-https=true
I0227 17:07:34.117098       1 plugins.go:71] No cloud provider specified.
I0227 17:07:34.549806       1 master.go:368] Node port range unspecified. Defaulting to 30000-32767.
[restful] 2016/02/27 17:07:34 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://172.31.29.111:443/swaggerapi/
[restful] 2016/02/27 17:07:34 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] https://172.31.29.111:443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
E0227 17:07:34.659701       1 cacher.go:149] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:115: Failed to list *api.Pod: 501: All the given peers are not reachable (failed to propose on members [https://172.31.29.111:2379] twice [last error: Get https://172.31.29.111:2379/v2/keys/registry/pods?quorum=false&recursive=true&sorted=true: remote error: bad certificate]) [0]`

The certificate should be good though. If I execute an interactive shell within that Docker image, I can get the etcd URL via curl without any issues. *So, what is going wrong in this case and how do I fix it?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I could solve this by using `--etcd-config` instead of `--etcd-servers`:

`docker run -p 443:443 -v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes:ro -v /etc/ssl/etcd:/etc/ssl/etcd:ro gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.2 /hyperkube apiserver --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1 --etcd-config=/etc/kubernetes/etcd.client.conf --allow-privileged=true --service-cluster-ip-range=10.3.0.0/24 --secure-port=443 --advertise-address=172.31.29.111 --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota --kubelet-certificate-authority=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client.pem --kubelet-client-key=/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client-key.pem --client-ca-file=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem --tls-cert-file=/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client.pem --tls-private-key-file=/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client-key.pem`

### etcd.client.conf:

`{
  "cluster": {
    "machines": [ "https://172.31.29.111:2379" ]
  },
  "config": {
    "certFile": "/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client.pem",
    "keyFile": "/etc/ssl/etcd/master1-master-client-key.pem"
   }
}`